# Sum of all comma-separated values from a single column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need a formula to sum all values from a single column that is comma-separated.

```
column A1 = 10,20,30,40

B1 = formula to result 100
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found answer, i hope, will be useful for all.

```
=sum(split(A1,","))
```

Thanks
jaikey sarraf